# javaFX: Wrong Merge sort animation result

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, javafx, mergesort

I am implementing a merge sort animation with some rectangles using javaFX. I use some function of animation to do it. However, The translate route is wrong. I check my code over and over again and do not find the problem. The problem might be in the merge method, but I can not find where the problem is. I use absolute coordinates to locate nodes: [javaFX:move shapes with absolute coordinates using translatetransition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993423/javafxmove-shapes-with-absolute-coordinates-using-translatetransition). Who can help me??

These are code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
double speed = 400;

int[] helper;

final ArrayList<Integer> CenterX = new ArrayList();
int listindex = 0;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    ArrayList<StackPane> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        int num = random.nextInt(10);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(40, (num * 10) + 50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.valueOf("#FF7F50"));
        Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(num));
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setPrefSize(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        stackPane.setId(String.valueOf(num));
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, text);
        StackPane.setAlignment(text,Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        stackPane.setTranslateX(60*i);
        list.add(stackPane);
    }


    pane.getChildren().addAll(list);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    HBox hBox1 = new HBox();
    Button b = new Button("Sort");


    AnchorPane bottomPane = new AnchorPane();
    hBox1.getChildren().add(b);
    bottomPane.getChildren().add(hBox1);     
    borderPane.setBottom(bottomPane);


    b.setOnAction(event -> {
        SequentialTransition sq = new SequentialTransition();
        int[] = arr;
        arr = generateArray(list);
        sq = MergeSort(arr, list,sq);
        b.setDisable(true);
        sq.play();
        sq.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                b.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
        b.setDisable(false);

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,800, 800);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Sorting");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        int centerx = (int) list.get(i).getLayoutX();
        CenterX.add(i,centerx+60*i);
        System.out.println(centerx+60*i);

    }
}



private int[] generateArray(List<StackPane> list) {
    int arr[] = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).getId());
    }
    return arr;
}

private TranslateTransition AddtoOriginal(StackPane sp, double speed,int X){
    TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition();
    t.setNode(sp);
    t.setDuration(Duration.millis(speed));
    t.setToX(X);
    t.setToY(300);
    return t;

}

public SequentialTransition MergeSort(int arr[],ArrayList<StackPane> list,SequentialTransition sq) {
    int number = arr.length;
    this.helper = new int[number];
    mergesort(0, number - 1,arr,sq,list);
    return sq;
}

private void mergesort(int low, int high,int arr[],SequentialTransition sq,ArrayList<StackPane> list) {
    // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
    if (low < high) {
            // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
            int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
            // Sort the left side of the array
            mergesort(low, middle,arr,sq,list);
            // Sort the right side of the array
            mergesort(middle + 1, high,arr,sq,list);
            // Combine them both
            merge(low, middle, high,arr,list,sq);
    }

}


private void merge(int low, int middle, int high,int arr[],ArrayList<StackPane> list,SequentialTransition sq) {
// Copy both parts into the helper array
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            helper[i] = arr[i];

    }
    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;
    // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
    // to the original array

    while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
            if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
                    arr[k] = helper[i];
                    sq.getChildren().add(AddtoOriginal(list.get(i),speed,CenterX.get(k)));
                    i++;
            } else {
                    arr[k] = helper[j];
                    sq.getChildren().add(AddtoOriginal(list.get(j),speed,CenterX.get(k)));
                    j++;
            }
            k++;
    }
    // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
    while (i <= middle) {
            arr[k] = helper[i];
            sq.getChildren().add(AddtoOriginal(list.get(i),speed,CenterX.get(k)));
            k++;
            i++;
    }

    ParallelTransition pl = new ParallelTransition();
    ArrayList<TranslateTransition> Transitionlist = new ArrayList<>(high-low);

    for (int z = low; z <= high; z++) {
        TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition();
        t.setNode(list.get(z));
        t.setDuration(Duration.millis(speed));
        t.setByY(-300);
        Transitionlist.add(t);  
}
pl.getChildren().addAll(Transitionlist);
sq.getChildren().add(pl);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Similar to your previously deleted question, this is related to [Javafx : swap rectangle shapes along with sawping array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026018/javafx-swap-rectangle-shapes-along-with-sawping-array-elements).  Does the solution there not help you?

Comment: @jewelsea But I don't know where the problem is. I've added the `SequentialTransition` to each translation. I've also relocated the position of the rectangle in each loop.

Comment: If you want help debugging your particular solution, you should provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something somebody could just copy and paste to replicate your problem.  Otherwise it is rather difficult for somebody to assist you.  Even then, it might be a little bit tricky with this kind of problem.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for your reminder. I will provide it later.

Comment: @jewelsea Can you check the code? Is it an mcve?

Comment: Yes it is an mcve, I'll check it if I can find the time.

Comment: @jewelsea ok, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Issues with your code and how to fix them*

Your main issue is that when you do something like this:

```
arr[k] = helper[j];
sq.getChildren().add(AddtoOriginal(list.get(j),speed,CenterX.get(k)));
```

What you are doing is having some arrays (`arr` and `helper`) that represent the values being sorted and you move the values within the positions in the array (in the assignment), but when you run the `AddToOriginal` routine you are not also moving the values in the list which is representing the visual display.  So what is happening is that the visual display is becoming out of sync with the sorted array.

Also the merge sort algorithm (as you have it implemented) is not an in place sort in memory, there are actually two arrays involved, the `arr` array and the `helper` array, the helper is necessary to keep track of original values when you assign arr values so that the original values don't get overwritten.  You need to do the same thing with the visual representation.  For the sample code I implemented below based upon your original code, what I did was add an extra array of `helperNodes` which keep track of the positional references of the helper array, but in a visual form.

Putting both those things together, whenever you swap a node, you do an extra statement like this, to keep the visual list inline with the value array that you are manipulating:

```
arr[k] = helper[j];
list.set(k, helperNodes[j]);
sq.getChildren().add(move(helperNodes[j], k * SPACING));
```

Also, note that the swapping move is based upon the unmutated `helperNodes[j]` elements and not the `list.get(j)` elements, which may have already been mutated.  What the above code is doing is mirroring the logic of the value assignment with the manipulation of the visual list array and the animated move in the `sq` sequential transition.

One additional issue is that the algorithm you have for merge sort doesn't do anything when nodes in the right part of the merge segment to be sorted are already in order.  However, you are performing an animated move of all of the elements in a merge segment back up to their original starting height.  So you need to add a little extra code to do that visual animation even though the value position in the array hasn't changed.

If you found this difficult, don't worry (it's not as easy as it seems IMO :-)

*Credit*

I am guessing (perhaps wrongly) that your merge sorting algorithm was based on the [Vogella Merge Sort Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html).  If so, it is nice to acknowledge that in the question as it helps understand the source of inspiration in context (if not, you can just ignore this note).

*Unsorted*

[image: unsorted]

*Sorting In Progress*

[image: in progress]

*Sorted*

[image: sorted]

*Sample App*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.*;

public class Merge extends Application {
    private static final int N_VALUES = 13;
    private static final int SPACING = 60;
    private static final int SORT_GROUP_MOVE_DELTA = 200;

    private static final Duration SPEED = Duration.millis(400);

    private int[] helper;
    private StackPane[] helperNodes;
    private Random random = new Random(5);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane displayPane = new Pane();
        ArrayList<StackPane> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N_VALUES; i++) {
            StackPane stackPane = createValueNode(i);
            list.add(stackPane);
        }

        displayPane.getChildren().addAll(list);

        Button sortButton = new Button("Sort");
        sortButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            SequentialTransition sq = new SequentialTransition();
            int[] arr = generateArray(list);
            sq = mergeSort(arr, list, sq);
            sortButton.setDisable(true);
            sq.play();
            sq.setOnFinished(event1 -> sortButton.setDisable(false));
            sortButton.setDisable(false);
        });

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(displayPane);
        borderPane.setBottom(sortButton);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(sortButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(sortButton, new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Sorting");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private StackPane createValueNode(int i) {
        int num = random.nextInt(10);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(40, (num * 10) + 50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.valueOf("#FF7F50"));
        Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(num));
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setPrefSize(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        stackPane.setId(String.valueOf(num));
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, text);
        StackPane.setAlignment(text, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        stackPane.setTranslateX(SPACING * i);
        return stackPane;
    }


    private int[] generateArray(List<StackPane> list) {
        int arr[] = new int[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).getId());
        }
        return arr;
    }

    private TranslateTransition move(StackPane sp, int X) {
        TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition();
        t.setNode(sp);
        t.setDuration(SPEED);
        t.setToX(X);
        t.setToY(SORT_GROUP_MOVE_DELTA);
        return t;

    }

    public SequentialTransition mergeSort(int arr[], ArrayList<StackPane> list, SequentialTransition sq) {
        int number = arr.length;
        this.helper = new int[number];
        this.helperNodes = new StackPane[number];
        sortRange(0, number - 1, arr, sq, list);
        return sq;
    }

    private void sortRange(int low, int high, int arr[], SequentialTransition sq, ArrayList<StackPane> list) {
        // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high) {
            // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
            int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
            // Sort the left side of the array
            sortRange(low, middle, arr, sq, list);
            // Sort the right side of the array
            sortRange(middle + 1, high, arr, sq, list);
            // Combine them both
            merge(low, middle, high, arr, list, sq);
        }
    }


    private void merge(int low, int middle, int high, int arr[], ArrayList<StackPane> list, SequentialTransition sq) {
        // Copy both parts into the helper array
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            helper[i] = arr[i];
            helperNodes[i] = list.get(i);
        }

        int i = low;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = low;
        // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
        // to the original array

        while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
            if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
                arr[k] = helper[i];
                list.set(k, helperNodes[i]);
                sq.getChildren().add(move(helperNodes[i], k * SPACING));
                i++;
            } else {
                arr[k] = helper[j];
                list.set(k, helperNodes[j]);
                sq.getChildren().add(move(helperNodes[j], k * SPACING));
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
        while (i <= middle) {
            arr[k] = helper[i];
            list.set(k, helperNodes[i]);
            sq.getChildren().add(move(helperNodes[i], k * SPACING));
            k++;
            i++;
        }

        // Even if we didn't move in the array because it was already ordered, 
        // move on screen for any remaining nodes in the target array.
        while (j <= high) {
            sq.getChildren().add(move(helperNodes[j], k * SPACING));
            k++;
            j++;
        }

        ParallelTransition moveUp = new ParallelTransition();

        for (int z = low; z <= high; z++) {
            TranslateTransition moveNodeUp = new TranslateTransition();
            moveNodeUp.setNode(helperNodes[z]);
            moveNodeUp.setDuration(SPEED);
            moveNodeUp.setByY(-SORT_GROUP_MOVE_DELTA);
            moveUp.getChildren().add(moveNodeUp);
        }

        sq.getChildren().add(moveUp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Possible Alternate Implementation*

One thing you could do is create a SortableNode class to replace the StackPane that you are defining to hold the values.  The sortable node could keep the value of the node in a field rather than in an ID.  The sortable node could also implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).  Then your merge sort algorithm could be updated to take a list of comparable objects as input rather than an array of ints.  That way you wouldn't need to keep track of separate arrays for the values and visual representations within the sort 
algorithm (and keep them in sync).  That would likely simplify the implementation a little bit.  But I won't add an additional sample here to implement this alternate approach (as the current sample above seems to work just fine ;-)

Comment: Thank u sooooo much!! I will try your suggestion(the alternate approach) later. Yes, the merge sort is based on that link. I am sorry that I don't mention it in the question. I will supply it.